# Wordpress Custom font not found

Tags: wordpress, css, fonts, wordpress-theming, font-family

I created a custom wordpress theme from scratch 
I am trying to use custom font
what I done
upload font to `wp-content/themes/mythemefolder/fonts/fontfolder`
 in theme default style.css

```
@font-face {
        font-family: "fontname";
        src: url('fonts/fontfolder/fontname.otf');
}
*{font-family: "fontname";}
```

when I visti page text are not in desired font
I check console show error :

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)  http://domainname.com/wp-content/themes/mythemefolder/fonts/fontfolder/fontname.otf
```

path of font in console is correct but still font not working

what mistake I am making

thanks in advance for help

Comment: can you give a link of the site to check?

Comment: @AhmedGinani yes sure - http://digiw3lab.com/wp/

Comment: upload all font extenstion otf,ttf, woff, eot  .. you are currently using only otf format..

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the permission of the font files included on the path.

You can do that via FTP or command line tools.

Via FTP : Change the file permission via right click , it must be 644 for file and 777 for folder.

Via command line,

```
find your_folder_name -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
find your_folder_name -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

Comment: path exist in console if u click the path, font will open in application tab & permission is already 755 to folder & 644 to files